# How to derive the sensitivity of the roots of a polynomial to its coefficients?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I have a cubic polynomial

$$f(x)=a_o x^3+a_1x^2+a_2x+a_0=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

but no closed form for its roots, i.e., I do not have closed form expressions for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ in terms of the coefficients $a_0$ to $a_3$. However is there a means to derive the sensitivity of the roots with respect to the coefficients, i.e., $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial a_1}$, etc?

Answer (score 4):

If the polynomial is $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^3 a_i x^{3-i}$, you can get the derivative of a simple root
by differentiating the implicit equation $P(x) = 0$. It gives
$$x^{3-i} + P^\prime(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial a_i} = 0$$
hence
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial a_i} = - \frac{x^{3-i}}{P^\prime(x)}$$

Comment: I found this description of the procedure helpful as well: https://www.skewray.com/articles/how-do-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-depend-on-the-coefficients Additionally, it mentions how to deal with the singular case $P^\prime(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$a_o x^3+a_1x^2+a_2x+a_0=a_0(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2),$$ where $a_0\neq0.$

You can use the Cardano's formula. See here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method

Comment: I like Nickall's new approach to the cubic for finding the roots: http://nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/cubic1993.pdf